# False negative in Azure Application Insights Availability Test

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-availability-set

I have setup Availability Test using Application Insights and using uptrends.com. I am pinging simple http resources. This resource does redirects before it returns 200.

I am getting a lot of errors in azure AI, from certain regions only. I cannot confirm, in any way (not via VMs deployed in that region, not via other services like uptrends.com) that there are failures.

The error is:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [...]:443

The failure occurs after just 20 seconds, when I have timeout configured at 120 seconds.

It appears Availability Tests are giving me false negatives ... any ideas?

[image: False negatives]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen when the IP address of "Availability Test clients" in this "partiular Azure region (*from where the failure is being noticed frequently*)" is not added to the allowed list on the Firewall/security system. Please refer to [Availability tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses#availability-tests) and [Addresses grouped by location (Azure Public Cloud)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses#addresses-grouped-by-location-azure-public-cloud) table in the above link to get all the required addresses related to "Availability Test Clients" of a particular Azure region and ensure that they are added to your firewall's Allowed List.

For more details, you may also refer to the discussion here on similar topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/755004/index.html